# There is an some errors come during creating my first react app?

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am started learning ReactJS today ,but I got some problems during creating an my first React app. Please guys can you help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLNSD.png)

Comment: try with this program find out who blocked the file: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess what's going wrong, because I do not even see the command that you entered.

But if you are really new to react I suggest you to start with [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app). At least you get a minimum valuable react js app running.

Comment: Yes I have used npm create-react-app app_name but, after running I have got some errors and not showing the reasult.

Comment: Here s another wild guess. Execute this commands in your terminal one by one.

`cd demo` and then

`npm start`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what is breaking your code here, however I recommend you to do the following to get your react app started.

Pre-requisites: Please ensure you have **Node Package Manager** installed on your computer

1. Open Terminal
2. Use the command
   `npx create-react-app my-app`
3. Go into the active directory
   `cd my-app`
4. Start your newly created React application with the command
   `npm start`
5. You should see the development server running on port 3000

Note: Use `npx` instead of `npm` while creating your react application.

> **NPM** - Manages packages and installs them |
> **NPX** - A tool for executing Node packages